# I used a recursive function to modify a string, but if the string is too large the function returns nothing

Tags: python, string, recursion, silent

I made a mutation function that changes every character in a string 1% of the time. To do this, I made a helper function that picks a character from a list and substitutes it in the old characters place. However, in the case where the new character picked matches the old character to be replaced, the mutation function is supposed to insert the old character twice. This makes things tricky because I can no longer just iterate through the string, since it might grow as it's iterated through. To solve this, I made the mutation function recursive. The code for this is below:

```
import sys
from numpy import random
from random import randrange

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

def PickRandomOtherBase(base_character):
    bases = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T', '-'] 
    new_character = bases[randrange(0, len(bases))]
    if new_character == base_character.upper():
        return new_character + base_character.upper()
    else:
        return new_character

def AddMutations(sequence_string, mutation_rate=0.01):
    # base case
    if not sequence_string:
        return ''
    # otherwise
    rng = random.default_rng()
    m_flag = rng.binomial(1, mutation_rate)
    current_char = sequence_string[0]
    if m_flag:
        current_char = PickRandomOtherBase(current_char)
    return ''.join([current_char, AddMutations(sequence_string[1:], mutation_rate=mutation_rate)])

AddMutations('acgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctga',
mutation_rate=1)
```

This works for small strings, but for large strings it returns the following error:
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

I set the recursion limit using `sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)`.
I found through trial and error that, no matter how high I set the recursion limit, the function will not return anything if the input string is higher than about 2150 characters.

At this point I figure I can rewrite this code to just not be recursive, but I am stumped as to why this doesn't work. I didn't think the memory cost would be so high as to not function at all, and the silent failing isn't giving me much to work with in the way of troubleshooting.

When I try to print the function output with long strings, it prints nothing.
It seems like there is a silent failure going on here too, because when I try to print anything, even the string 'foo' after calling this function on a long string, nothing is printed.

Comment: _the function will silently fail_ what does this mean?  The function returns a blank string?  The function raises a recursion exception?  The function runs forever and never returns?

Comment: "no matter how high I set the recursion limit, the function will silently fail if the input string is higher than about 2150 characters." please provide a [mcve]. Functions never "return nothing". They *always* return *something* **or** they raise an exception (or perhaps, terminate the python process, I guess).

Comment: And just as a general observation, this does not seem like a good use case for recursion.

Comment: "When I try to print the function output with long strings, it prints nothing." what **exactly** are you doing?

Comment: Make a [mcve].  We can't run your code to reproduce the issue.  The built-in `random` module has no `default_rng`, `PickRandomOtherBase` isn't defined, etc.  If you are using 3rd party modules, then list them.

Comment: Use a `list(sequence_string)` which is mutable.  You can insert and change in an iterative function instead of recursion.

Comment: I have updated the initial post to hopefully clear up confusion. I probably won't use recursion here at this point, but I would like to understand what's going on. The output, as far as I can tell, is nothing. The code runs without giving errors. When I try to print the output of the function, nothing is printed. When I try to run any print statement after running this function with a long string, a string that's 2200 characters long comprised of the characters 'a' 'c' 'g' and 't', even when it's just `print('foo')`, nothing is printed, which makes me think there may be a silent error.

Comment: But are you sure that your code finished running, and that it isn't just taking much more time than you expected?

Comment: I suspect your recursive solution has exponential complexity, which makes it take a really long time for large inputs.

Comment: Yes, I am running though bash and it is giving me another command prompt.

Comment: A good general solution for your original problem is to iterate from the end rather than the beginning. When you insert into the string, it won't affect the lower indexes.

Comment: Avoid unnecessary operations in code like this: Call `random.default_rng()` only once. Don't use a list comprehension in the `join()` argument, just use the generator directly.

Comment: Can't repeat on Windows.  Just raises `RecursionError` for large strings.

Comment: There's no need to call `join()` at all. Just do `return current_char + AddMutations(...)`

Comment: Just added the sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) line which hopefully makes the code fully reproducible.

Comment: running the code that is currently there just outputs a string.

Comment: @Barmar *"Don't use a list comprehension in the join() argument, just use the generator directly"* - Why? It's more efficient with the list comp.

Comment: What is your question? You didn't ask any.

Comment: @KellyBundy Really? Doesn't that mean that the memory for the list has to be allocated? Is it because `join()` has optimizations when it knows the number of items rather than processing a stream?

Comment: @Barmar It [creates a list anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/12671057).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is reproducible, but missing a `print` for the result of `AddMutations`.  It works otherwise :)

Here is an iterative solution:

```py
from numpy import random
from random import choice

# single initialization globals
bases = 'ACGT-'
rng = random.default_rng()

def PickRandomOtherBase(base_character):
    new_character = choice(bases)
    if new_character == base_character:
        return base_character * 2
    else:
        return new_character

def AddMutations(sequence_string, mutation_rate=0.01):
    result = list(sequence_string.upper())  # Use a mutable list
    for i, c in enumerate(result):
        m_flag = rng.binomial(1, mutation_rate)
        if m_flag:
            result[i] = PickRandomOtherBase(c)  # mutate
    return ''.join(result)

print(AddMutations('acgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctgaacgcgacgttggttaaccttaaacccgggttttgggtttgccaccgctga',
mutation_rate=1))
```

Output:

```
CG-T-TCCATT-GG-TTC-GTTCGCGG--GGGA-GCGCTGG-TTGCGGCCCCGCCGT-A-GAAAC-ATTTCCTGG-A--CCGCTTTT-GGCCCCT-GAATTAGAC-T-C---TCTAA-ATTTCGAC-GGCGG-CCCGTTCCT--CC-GGAAA-TTCCCAGCAGGACC-GCCTGTTGGAA-T-CCACCCACTTAGG---TCCCCCG-AAGCCAAAGGTAATTGGGACGCGAGCCGGTTTC-AAAA-CT--CCGGA-AGGG-GCTTGA--GCCATGGATCTTCCAGGACTT-TTAAA-TT-GACG--CCACCCTAGAGGCGGGGTC-GT-AA-T-T-GCTTTAGGGCGCCCTAACCCC-T-GGCCACCC-CCCA-G-GGACCAAGCCG--CTTGCCATGGG-A--AATTAC-GTCATCCCCT--AGGTC-GGG-AT-G--TAAA-TGAACCACCAATCGCTTCGGTTTCGT-ACGCCGGGC--CAAT---TC-AATTATCCC--TT-GAACC-G--CTT-TTTTCAGGTT-GCTCCT-CC--TTCAACGTT-CA-C-A-CC-GGTACCTAAGGGTAATT--CTGGC-CTTGGGCCTTTACCC-CAA-ACCAGGCTTTTCACGAAAAGT-ACT-CCTG-CAATTTTAGGGGT-TT-TGAAAACCGG-CC-GTCGCGAGGCGT-ATTAAGG--ACTAATACCCC--G--A-GGCCCTAGTAA-AGGG-CAATTCCCCCTT-C-TTTTACCC-TGCGCCCCA--TT---CGGC-G--TCCCCCTGG--CCCGGGGAGGCACC-CTTTAATCCGATCAA-TAGG-CCCA-GGAGG-TTTTAAGTAGTCCCGGC-AC-TCACCTTGGATT-GGCCTG-G-GCCCCGGGCCGGCCAGGGGC-CGGATCACCACCA-TTTTGGGCAA-GT-CCTG-TGAGTC-TGATA-AC--TCCGG-GACGAGGCC-TAAAAGGGGCGAGG-CTTGTTT-ACC-CCAAGTTTTCTC-GTTAC-TTACCG-CGGTTAAAAGTA-GGTGT--ATCC---G---AA-GA-A-TGCCAATGGG-CTTGGGT-CC-T--GGGCCT-AC--CCTTGTTCCCCATTGAATGATTATC--TTTTC-TTTTCACC-CCTGG----CT-CCACTTCTT----CTAATTC--TTG-CGGTGG--CGGATTTT-A-CC-GGACCCGG-CCCTAGGAATT-AGG-CATGTT-G-TC-CCAAAT-GTTA-GGTATTTTATTAA-T-TCTTAATT-GGGGGGGAAGGTT-AACCCCCGCGAA-GTGC--GGTTCGGCGGTTTTTTC--TCCTT-TT-CTGC-AGT-AGTGGA-GAAGGGG-AAGGCCT-C-TT-TTC-CCATT-CA-CTAGG-GC-AACCC-AGGGGAGGG--CG-GGTTACC-CC-GATGGAGTTGGGCGGA--TTAGCCCCACCTTCAAAAACCCTAAACG-GGA-TTAAGCCG-GG-AAACCCCCATACTTGGGTA-CAACCAT-CCCG-ATC-CGAGTAA-AATTATT-TTTTTGGC-GCCATCATTCG-GGCCCCA--CA-TGAGG-CTGGCC-CTC-AT-C-CG-G--GCAATTACCACC-TTA-A-TTTTTTCCTA-TTTTA-AA-GGCCA--CGAAGG-GGAA-GTTGTCTG-A-GGGGCTTATTGGTAA-AACC-AACCTTCC--TGGT-TAAG-A-CGG-TTAAAAT-AGTGCACCAGGGGATTGAGGG-AACAGGGTCATGGCCACAA-TA-C-GCG-GGT-A--A-A-AAAAGGTGGG-AGATTCCCGG-GCATCCCTTT-GGGC--TATCACTTGGGACA-AACCA-CAAAA--GCCC-CTTAGGAGGCTT-TTAGGGTTGG-GAAAT-CGGG-A-GTTTGGCGAATG-G-GG-TTA-TGGTT-G--GGTTT-TTGGCCCC--CCAAGGG-TGGGCCAAAG-CGCCAAC---C-T-T-CC--C--GTTCATGGGCA-CCT-AATAAT-TGGGTGGAAAGGTTGCT-GTGGACCC-CACCGTGGTGTTAAGG-C-ATTGGA-CT-CCCTTTTTG-TCAA-TG-GG-CTT-GCCTC-C-TTTGGGGGTCG---T--AAA-TC-TGGATTGGAAAAGGGTGGGT-ATTAGGAAGTCCA---TCTGTA--ATT-GTGGC-G-T-TTGGT-AC-TAAAGGAAT-C-AGGTTC-AAAACCGTG-TACAA-GCTTTAGGG-TT-CCTCTCCGGACT-T-GGCCCTAC--TTAGAAT-TC--AA-CC-TTTAACCTTCA-TT-AACCTGTGGGGTTATT---AAAGTTTCT-TTC-CCCGATTCAAGT--A-CCGGCTTTCGAGGCCCC-T-ACCAA-T-CTTC-GG--GGTCA-TCCAGGCTCCCGGGGC-AC-TTGGGGGGGGG-G-T-GATACAACGACC-AA-ATTA--TTA-CA-CGG---GCCCA-CCA-GGAGGCTTAT--AA-AGGGAGGCTCCATA-TTTTGACTTCAAAACC-CAAAAA-CCATAACTT-GAAA-GCA--TAAACC-ACT-G-CAC-TA-TTTCC-GC-TAG-CT-G--ACCTTAA-GGGG-GAC-GTGTGG-GTTAATGGAACA-AACCATTTGT-CACAAAATACCT---CA-CAGGC-ACGTGGCC-TCGG-
```

Comment: Hmm, this is an exceptional case where I might prefer `for i in range(len(result))` over `enumerate`. That's likely more efficient here (since only 1% of the characters are used) and it might be clearer to write `result[i] = PickRandomOtherBase(result[i])` (no need for an extra variable `c` to understand and track).